# Image capture (ICA) driver as dext, is it possible?

Tags: macos, driverkit

I'm trying to rebuild old scanner driver as dext, according to Apple recommendations.

Old version used ICADevices framework to register and communicate with calling application. But it is not available for DriverKit, and I can't find any replacement.  Does anyone know which interface should I use instead?

I revised a few scanner drivers from different vendors, declared as available for the latest OSX version, but didn't see any dext based solution.

Comment: There is no DriverKit SDK framework for image capture devices as of macOS 14/Sonoma. Are you encountering a specific problem with the ICADevices framework? Or does the old driver use a kext in combination with an ICADevices based driver? In the latter case, you should be able to replace the kext with a dext, with only minor modifications to the ICADevices driver.

Comment: Thanks! The primary problem was matching ICADevices driver to the device,and it's still not solved. Earlier scanners vid/pid were defined in DeviceMatchingInfo.plist, but now that doesn't work.

Comment: This discussion is now veering far off the original question, you may have more luck getting a response by posting/rewriting your question with specifics of the problem you are facing with your ICADevices based driver. I don't have any specific hands on experience with scanner drivers on macOS yet, but I could imagine a bunch of reasons why it might not be working. First and foremost would be code signing - a lot other kinds of user space drivers will only work with Developer ID signed, notarised binaries. System logs at time of hotplug might give you some clues.